# Convert character string list into dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, text, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping the Newark Liberty International Airport's website to keep track of their daily schedules. Here is the piece of code I have developed:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html('https://www.airport-ewr.com/newark-departures-terminal-C?
tp=6&day=tomorrow')

population <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="flight_detail"]') %>% 
              html_text() %>% gsub(pattern = '\\t|\\r|\\n', replacement = ' ') %>% 
              trimws() %>% gsub(pattern = '\\s+', replacement = " ")
```

gsub() is for removing the leading and trailing whitespaces and extra spaces within the text. The code works well and I have attached the snippet of the output:

[image]

I want to convert this character string into a dataframe which would contain values as shown below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: Can you please share data as text? Image will not help people to work on your problem.

Comment: Please do not show images of data, just give the data itself (preferably with an easy-to-copy format like `dput(head(x))`. This is absolutely a [regular-expression problem](https://xkcd.com/1171/), which means it will take a lot of work to make it robust. Is there another format in which you can retrieve that data?

Comment: It might be easier to parse as an XML

Comment: You could use `trimws`. What is the algorithm for splitting this string? What have you tried?

Comment: Please post the snippet as plaintext, to make your example reproducible, so people can copy-and-paste it. That's the startpoint for this question.

Comment: It's not necessarily a regex problem, a scraping package is probably better: you can see you can use the newlines or XML tags to delimit fields. This is why scraping packages exist: to prevent you drowning in a  brittle and unmaintainable soup of regexes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html('https://www.airport-ewr.com/newark-departures-terminal-C?tp=6&day=tomorrow')


population <- url %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="flight_detail"]') %>% 
              html_text()
```

First we read in the raw text rows. Then I noticed that each column is separated by `\n` but sometimes there's more than one, so first we `gsub` out the extra `\n` delimiters, then string split by `\n`, and `rbind` the output into a `data.frame`

```
popDF <- as.data.frame(
  do.call('rbind',strsplit(gsub("(\\n)+", "\\\n",population),split="\n", fixed=TRUE))
)


  V1               V2                V3      V4       V5                V6 V7      V8                       V9
1      Austin  (AUS)   United Airlines  UA 2427 06:00 am Depart:  06:00 am  C Term. C  Scheduled - On-time [+]
2      Austin  (AUS)               SAS  SK 6868 06:00 am Depart:  06:00 am  C Term. C  Scheduled - On-time [+]
3      Boston  (BOS)   United Airlines  UA 1699 06:00 am Depart:  06:00 am  C Term. C  Scheduled - On-time [+]
4    Columbus  (CMH)          CommutAir C5 4973 06:00 am Depart:  06:00 am  C Term. C  Scheduled - On-time [+]
5    Columbus  (CMH)   United Airlines  UA 4973 06:00 am Depart:  06:00 am  C Term. C  Scheduled - On-time [+]
6     Detroit  (DTW)  Republic Airlines YX 3482 06:00 am Depart:  06:00 am  C Term. C  Scheduled - On-time [+]
```